http-post request fails every 2nd iteration on arduino
I'm kinda losing it. I have a pretty simple http POST request with in my code, which kinda works, but kinda doesn't. That solely depends on the time(out). Please have a look at this:
void sendUpdateToServer(int l_rotations) {
  http.begin(server);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  char postQuery[100];
  snprintf(postQuery, sizeof(postQuery), "speed=%d&username=DasSaffe", l_rotations);
  
  Serial.println(postQuery);

  String httpRequestData = postQuery;
  int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);

  if (httpResponseCode > 0) {
    String response = http.getString();  //Get the response to the request
    Serial.println(response);            //Print request answer
  } else {
    Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  http.end();
}

currentMillis = millis(); 
if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period) {
    if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        initWiFi();
    }
    Serial.println();
    sendUpdateToServer(rotations);
    startMillis = currentMillis;
    rotations = 1;
} 

Basically, my code runs every second / 5 seconds / 10 seconds. I adjust that in a global variable, which I left out here. But anyway.
If I run this code every second, my output looks like this:
called with 1 km/h from DasSaffe
Sent update to server 
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe
called with 1 km/h from DasSaffe
Sent update to server 
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe
called with 1 km/h from DasSaffe
Sent update to server 
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe 

This is the success-response code, so it does work all the time.
However, if I run it every 5 or 10 seconds, every other iteration fails. So the complete opposite if what I thought would happen, if I "spam" the server.
Sent update to server
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe 
called with 1 km/h from DasSaffe (success)
Sent update to server 
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe
Error on sending POST: -2 (fail)
Sent update to server
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe
called with 1 km/h from DasSaffe (success)
Sent update to server 
post-query-string: speed=1&username=DasSaffe
Error on sending POST: -2 (fail)

This continues forever. success, fail, success, fail,success, fail,success, fail,.....
As a side-note:
I have
HTTPClient http;

as a global variable.
Am I missing something obvious? Why does it work on shorter intervals but not on longer ones? According to the docs, the error -2 is HTTPC_ERROR_SEND_HEADER_FAILED I tried posting several requests with POSTMAN in shorter intervals as well and there it works. It also works if I run it every 5 seconds from within POSTMAN. The Query-string is also always the same. I tried NUL-terminating the string as well, but that didn't help either. It might also be a good idea to keep the connection open all the time, maybe?
Any help appreciated
